# Outlook 2007 - Business Contact Manager Without Cached Mode

Tags: outlook

Is it possible to employ **Business Contact Manager 2007** without running **Outlook in Cached mode**?

According to all the reasearch I have done this is a prerequisite, and certainly upon installing and testing it seems to be the case, but keeping local copies of inboxes is simply too large a security hole for us, I find it difficult to believe that this is a requirement!

Thanks in advance for your responses!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer on the most basic level here is No.

But the security hole created by storing copies of Mailboxes on workstations can be worked around, it is as simple as moving the local mailbox storage file (.ost file) to a secure server then re wiring outlook to find it in its new location.

Hope this helps someone!